# Cannot request Bluetooth permission on Wear OS Samsung Galaxy Watch 4

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions, wear-os, samsung-galaxy-watch-4

I've created a sample Wear OS app, which should discover BLE devices, but my code requires Bluetooth permission. When I put these lines in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

corresponding permission is not displayed in settings/apps/permissions and every permission request does nothing. By the way, my BLE-devices (a speaker and a esp-32) is not shown in settings/Bluetooth also.

How can I grant Bluetooth permissions for my app or how can I connect BLE device to my watch?

upd:
I tried these:

```
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH), 1001)
        }

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT), 1001)
        }

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN), 1001)
        }

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN), 1001)
        }
```

But dialogs windows still are not displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions), you need particular permissions in based of the target Android API version.

If your app targets **Android 11 (API level 30)** or lower, declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file:

- **BLUETOOTH** is necessary to perform any Bluetooth classic or BLE communication, such as requesting a connection, accepting a connection, and transferring data.
- **ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** is necessary because, on Android 11 and lower, a Bluetooth scan could potentially be used to gather information about the location of the user.

If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, you can declare the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission instead of the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission.

In order to perform a scan to discover BLE devices the app must require explicitaly to the user the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` permission also to be declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

In my project (WearOS API version 28) I used this code in the  `onCreate` function of `MainActivity` class

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                1);
    }
```

And I overrided the `onRequestPermissionsResult` function

```
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                
                Logger.d("MainActivity","Permission approved");
            }  else {
                Logger.d("MainActivity","Error getting permission");
            }
            return;
    }

}
```

This works for me, I hope would help you

Answer (score 1):

there are some permissions like camera, bluetooth which need to be asked first and then manually provided. use this in the activity that loads first in your app.

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), 1001);
        }             //ask camera permissions
```

make sure to do required changes.

Comment: This wear app requests bluetooth permissions https://github.com/garanj/wearwind/blob/866b88e72dff3fa76c752828bd4e5283c3390463/app/src/main/java/com/garan/wearwind/FanActivity.kt#L92

Comment: @mordor619 I've modified my code with this (see upd description), but It didn't help

Comment: @Yuri Schimke, thanks, seems that location permission is also needed for bluetooth, I'll double check it and if it is a solution, I'll post an answer here.

Comment: @andrew try and give different value for each permission like 1001, 1002, so on..